# Swift: Deleting a row in a TableView (Core Data)

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview, delete-row

Evening ladies and gentleman,
I got a little problem with my TableView. I am using the code provided down below to delete a row in my tableview. But somehow the app crashes when I execute the delete swipe. The tableview uses core data. Does anyone of you know how to solve this?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
{

    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title:  "Delete", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in


        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        CoreDataManager.shared.safeContext()

        print("Löschen")
        success(true)
    })
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "trash1")
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
}
```

Comment: Whats the error

Comment: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: It's not enough information for me to reproduce the problem. If you can upload an example project to github or show me all the relevant problem, I can fix the problem

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. Which exact information do you need?

Comment: You have to remove the item also from the data source array unless you are using `NSFetchedResultsController`

Comment: This is what the array looks like in the Core Data file: "var todos = [Todo]()". For testing I wrote a function containing "todos.removeAll()" and called it in my view controller class and saved in my context. But nothing happend.

Comment: Problem solved, i got it